# sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
create PROC insert_Items(@Store varchar(20),@ID varchar(20),@Name varchar(20),@IDate varchar(11))
As
Declare @UDates varchar(11),
Declare @Quantity int,
Declare @Defects int
Select  @Quantity  From inserted 
Select  @Defects  From Inserted
set @UDates = getdate(), 
     @Remanders = @Defects - @Quantity
Insert Items(StoreName,ProductID,ProductName,Quantity,Defects,InsertedDate,UpdatedDate)
Values(@Store,@ID,@Name,@Quantity,@Defects,@IDate,@UDates)
```

The question is i want to get the value for Remainder in my table l

Comment: I do see a Remanders instead of Remainder i guess you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

If your table already contains a Remainder field, then simply add it to the INSERT statement like so :

```
    Insert Items(StoreName, ProductID, ProductName, Quantity, Defects, InsertedDate, UpdatedDate, Remainder) 
Values(@Store, @ID, @Name, @Quantity, @Defects, @IDate, @UDates, @Remainder)
```

A better option might be to make the Remainder column in the table a computed column.  That way you'll always have the value, even if the data wasn't added through your stored procedure.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean.  Are you saying you can't change the table?  If you need @Remanders to be returned from your stored procedure, then you can use Ralph's example of an output parameter or simply but the line 'RETURN @Remanders' at the end of the stored procedure

Comment: i dot the entering through vb.net so it can not be enter.this is how i want the end result to be .....@Remainder = @Quantity - @Defects

Comment: how do  i go by it the computed column

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE Items ADD Remainder AS Quantity - Defects'

Answer (score 0):

general practice is to [declare an OUTPUT parameter for the procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).  The caller will then get that value as the parameter.
for example

```
create proc outputdemo(@invalue int, @outvalue int output)
as
    set @outvalue = @invalue * 2
go

declare @myvalue int
exec outputdemo 10, @myvalue output
select @myvalue
```